# nested list to single column data frame R

Tags: r, dataframe, list, nested, lapply

I have a nested list like this -

[[1]]

[[1]][[1]]

[1] "{ABCE1 ALG8}{ACAA1 ACPP}" "1"                        "1"                        "0.832"                    "0.65"

[[1]][[2]]

[1] "{ABCE1 ALG8}{ACAA1 ACSL4}" "0.97"                      "0.962"                     "0.728"                     "0.7"

[[2]]

[[2]][[1]]

[1] "{ABCE1 ALG8}{ACAA1 ACPP}" "1"                        "1"                        "0.832"                    "0.65"

[[2]][[2]]

[1] "{ABCE1 ALG8}{ACAA1 ACSL4}" "0.97"                      "0.962"                     "0.728"                     "0.7"

[[3]]

[[3]][[1]]

[1] "{ABCE1 ALG8}{ACAA1 ACPP}" "1"                        "1"                        "0.832"                    "0.65"

[[3]][[2]]

[1] "{ABCE1 ALG8}{ACAA1 ACSL4}" "0.97"                      "0.962"                     "0.728"                     "0.7"

....

I want to convert it to tab-delimited format -

{ABCE1 ALG8}{ACAA1 ACPP} 1 1 0.832 0.65

{ABCE1 ALG8}{ACAA1 ACSL4} 0.97 0.962 0.728 0.7

{ABCE1 ALG8}{ACAA1 ACPP} 1 1 0.832 0.65

{ABCE1 ALG8}{ACAA1 ACSL4} 0.97 0.962 0.728 0.7

{ABCE1 ALG8}{ACAA1 ACPP} 1 1 0.832 0.65

{ABCE1 ALG8}{ACAA1 ACSL4} 0.97 0.962 0.728 0.7

Thanks for your suggestions!

Answer (score 0):

After doing more research, I found a solution -

lets say the nested list is stored in variable 'op', then the following will do the job -

```
df = data.frame(matrix(unlist(op), nrow=6, ncol = 5, byrow=T),stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```